# Tealium Javascript Code Extension How To Return A Variable

Tags: javascript, data-layer, tealium

I am trying to create a custom JavaScript code extension in Tealium to reduce the amount of Extensions needed to differentiate CTA's for icon links that do not have alt, or title tags. I am getting the value of my b.variable in my browser console. What I am stuck on is how to set the value of a variable and have it returned to my data-layer for later usage.

```
if (b.nav_icon){
  var classattr = b.nav_icon;
  if( classattr.indexOf('icon') >= 0 & classattr.indexOf('world-new') >= 0){
    var b.nav_icon = 'nav:Language Switcher';
  }
}
return b.nav_icon;
```

How do I set and return a variable back to the data-layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with I would recommend looking at this doc [TLC - The b Object](https://community.tealiumiq.com/t5/JavaScript-utag-js/The-b-Object/ta-p/13620).
From a JavaScript extension that is All Tags Scoped, you can only return true/false, to stop the execution of the event.

To set data for later use, you can either use `b` for event level storage, or for page level storage `utag.data` (if you are on the latest version of the loader file).

In the example above you can change to the following:

```
if (b.nav_icon){
  var classattr = b.nav_icon;
  if( classattr.indexOf('icon') >= 0 & classattr.indexOf('world-new') >= 0){
   b.nav_icon = 'nav:Language Switcher';
  }
}
```

Notice the removal of the `var` in the internal if statement and the `return`. We are now updating the value `b.nav_icon` to the new value.  Which can be used from other extensions or tags, in this event flow.

Comment: YOU ARE THEE MAN! I have read the b Object docs many times over and couldn't for the life of me figure out how to set the variable.. TY Ty gingacodemonkey